# Batch file command-line code for backing up Browser Passwords

Tags: batch-file, browser, command-line, cmd, password-recovery

I want to write a batch file for a usb pen drive which retrieves my stored passwords from my firefox browser and backs them up on the usb pen drive. Is there a command which can retrieve these passwords and, if so, is it possible to save the results to a txt file?

Thanks,
oblique

Comment: You can't get the actual passwords themselves, but you can make copies of the files that contain the passwords.

Comment: @SomethingDark can the passwords be easily read from these files or is some sort of software or decryption needed to extract them?

Comment: They're encrypted as hell. The .json file contains something that vaguely resembles base64 (it's not), and the .db file is pure hexadecimal.

Comment: I was sure I read somewhere that there was commands for this just like there is for retrieving user account or WiFi passwords but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to store your passwords as plain text on a USB drive. What happens if you misplace your USB drive?

If you want, you could backup your profile folder using a batch file, and that would include not only your passwords, but also bookmarks, extensions, etc. [Mozilla documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-are-my-logins-stored#w_use-the-password-manager-without-the-master-password) gives advantages/disadvantages to using the password manager inside Firefox.

> One advantage of using the Firefox Password Manager is that it stores
>   all your logins - your usernames and passwords - in one single place.
>   You can find your logins in the Firefox Password Manager and not worry
>   about forgetting where they are.
>
> On the other hand, putting all your logins in one place, unprotected,
>   can be risky. Theoretically, someone who has access to your computer
>   could open and view your logins in the Firefox Password Manager and go
>   on an Amazon shopping spree ! Fortunately, Firefox lets you use a
>   master password to prevent others from accessing your logins without
>   your permission.

It also recommends external password managers, but oddly, it doesn't mention [KeePass](http://keepass.info/). You could use it to store your Firefox passwords(or any other passwords for that matter). You can download the portable version and run it off your USB drive.